# Mysql left join to get unique topics

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables:

Topic table:

```
topic_id
2
3
4
```

like table:

```
topic_id         user_id
2                4
2                6
3                1
4                2
```

For a logged in user (use $user_id to represent), I need to return unique topics and a flag to indicate whether this user has liked this post or not.
For the above example, if the user id for the logged in user is 2, the return should be:

```
topic_id        liked
2               0 or NULL
3               0 or NULL
4               1
```

I have tried to leftJoin topic and like table with "like.user_id = $user_id OR like.user_id is NULL", but that will left out topics that have likes but haven't liked by the user. Could anyone help me with the query? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all topics from the topic table and use `LEFT JOIN` to merge them with rows from like table. After that you can filter `user_id` column with `IF` : if it is `null` then there are no records for this topic related to this user so flag is `0`, otherwise flag is `1`.

```
SELECT t.topic_id
     , IF(l.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS liked
FROM topic t LEFT JOIN like l ON t.topic_id= l.topic_id AND l.user_id = ?
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17861/9)

Comment: @Veedrac : Updated. In fact, I don't think that 'Use `LEFT JOIN`' is an explanation too (I am not saying that this is bad to write this, not at all, just to say that it is not better than nothing).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know SQL so it's hard for me to tell, but I think even the pointer to `LEFT JOIN` makes sure readers can extrapolate more easily from the example. OTOH, I'm really not the person to ask ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, by using your user id condition in sum will give you the count for each topic user has liked and 0 if not liked by user

```
select t.*,sum(lk.user_id = 2) liked from topic t
left join like_t lk on(t.topic_id= lk.topic_id)
group by t.topic_id
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17861/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all topics, then the most efficient way is to use a nested select:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from likes l where t.topic_id = l.topic_id)
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as liked
from topics t;
```

For optimal performance, this create an index on `likes(topic_id)`.

If you use a `join`, then you will need an aggregation (or distinct) somewhere in the query.  This method makes that operation unnecessary.